# How do I determine if a function is strictly increasing/decreasing

Tags: calculus

I have the following function:

$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{(x+1)}$

I've caculated the derivative to:

$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$

And the domain to: $(-\infty, -1)\cup(-1, \infty)$

I've also found two extreme point: $x=0,   x=-2$

I know that a function is strictly increasing if:
$f'(x)> 0$
and strictly decreasing if:
$f'(x)< 0$

I've calculated the intervalls where the funtcion is strictly increasing to:
$(-\infty, -2]\cup[0, \infty)$
and strictly decreasing to:
$[-2, -1)\cup(-1, 0]$

My question is if this is correct or if the intervalls should be:
$(-\infty, -2)\cup(0, \infty)$ and $(-2, -1)\cup(-1, 0)$ instead?
As you can notice I'm very unsecure whether I should use ( or [ at the extrempoints?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you:)

Comment: @PeterForeman Actually, they can (should !) be included. Think of $f(x) = x^2$ : this function is increasing on $[0, +\infty)$, even if $0$ is an extremum.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe You're correct. I'm so used to defining 'increasing' by $f'(x)\gt0$ rather than the correct definition namely $x\gt y\implies f(x)\gt f(y)$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes :) But one has to be careful with this. For example, $x \mapsto x^3$ **is** strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, whereas its derivative vanishes somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

If a continuous function is defined on $[a,b]$, then it is equivalent to say that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$, and that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

So in your case, the two options are equivalent.

Be careful that if the function is not continuous, it can be strictly increasing on $(a,b)$, but not increasing on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Really appreciate it:)